# Number Wheel/0-9 Decagon gear for board game?

Tags: game-design

Is there a 0-9 number wheel / plastic decagon thing available for board game construction?

[I previously asked a question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12450/keeping-track-of-many-independent-variables-on-a-physical-board) about possible techniques for tracking multiple variables. Here I am asking specifically about the feasibility of making a board which has little rotating decagons (about 25-50 of them), each of which cover the values 0-9, just like [this picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Combination_discs.png)  or [this one](http://www.trollandtoad.com/p921025.html).

Is there anywhere I can buy tiny decagon plastic rings like the first picture, to implant into a board with a little depth, that can be then be turned?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keeping track of many independent variables on a physical board?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12450/keeping-track-of-many-independent-variables-on-a-physical-board) , it doesn't seem like you need both of these questions that are basically asking the same thing.

Comment: @bwarner I'll explain my reasoning. In that question I am willing to accept any answer as to how I can track independent variables, for example I am considering the dice answer or some other mechanisms suggested. However in this question I specifically want to replicate the combination disks on a lock for a game board just like these http://www.trollandtoad.com/p921025.html

Comment: @bwarner I'll delete the answer if you think I should. Just wanted to see answers from a focus on that combination lock design.

Comment: @CodeCamper - In light of your intentions expressed in the comments, I've edited your question to be much more specific. These are now indeed two different questions.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for something like this? [MTG Cammander's Arsenal 100hp Spindown](http://www.trollandtoad.com/p921025.html)

These are very expensive, not sure how you'd get them cheaper. I've done a little Googling and come up with nothing. Perhaps you could get them 3D printed by [Shapeways](http://www.shapeways.com/)

In any case, I'd be concerned about how expensive these are, if you want to implement them across a game you want to sell it will become very prohibitive, and even if you managed to fund the release the game would have to be so expensive it would be hard to sell.

I'd recomened considering other systems, such as counters or even pen and paper. With counters you could provide counters that have various numerical values (in Magic I use little gems I got from China as +1/+1 counters, white = 1, green = 5 and red = 10) and with pen and paper you could provide wipe clean cards.

**EDIT**

I'm concerned that even if you can make these work the board will be very chunky, making for bigger boxes and further logistical issues. Here's another idea I just had: 3 disks of varying sizes, made of cardboard, with numbers printed on them, that can be pinned flat to the tile:

[image: Pinwheel]

This would take up less space and allow other things to be placed on the tile, as well as being vastly cheaper. The player would just turn the wheels to align with the arrow (perhaps better to have the arrow on the left hand side)

Comment: That picture you have provided is exactly what I am looking for. The only problem is I wanted to build it into the physical board. There will already be counters for other things because they will "move" but within each square there is a few numerical values which must be transparent to all players but increment/decrement. I have another question about this already, but this particular question is specifically how I could implement those spinning wheels and that picture you have provided is a start to what I am looking for. Of course at that price it'll cost me 1000$ a board + glue haha.

Comment: Heck if I can just find a place that sells plastic decagons I will draw the numbers on it myself and try to implement it into a board somehow. Sadly I can only find decagon rings made of metal meant for the human finger and not plastic made for the human board game.

Comment: I wonder how small I can make those spinning wheels and I'm trying to think how I can make them sturdy I would need at least 25 on the board in a 2 1/4*2 1/4" square each. Pretty awesome idea though. Any links to working versions of this wheel for sale? I think I will try to make one from scratch and see how it goes.

Comment: a 2" disc with 10 digits printed on it and a brad through the middle of the disc and a hole in the board... this would be pretty easy to do, and you could have 25 of them on a board easy enough.

Comment: Not having much luck finding examples @CodeCamper, but as Sparr say; they should be real easy to make. Make a large one out of thin card and a pin and then scale it down. As for strudiness You don't need to worry about that too much, they'll be flush with the board, and for now you only need to make a working version. Good luck, and if possible I'd love it if you could keep me in the loop about your game (you can reach me via http://oz.itsalocke.com)

Answer (score 1):

*The Mississippi Queen* is a board game that does almost exactly what you're asking for: dials, oriented vertically, that can be rotated.

[This image](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/107000/the-mississippi-queen) shows the dials in action: hexagonal disks that show a number from 0 to 5 along the edge. The dials can be taken out of the steamboats, and can also be rotated in place; if you're not specifically trying to rotate them, they hold their position just fine. There are two plastic pieces for each dial: the dial, and the place for it to sit. (The dials are just sitting loosely in a cup; there's no axle holding them in place.) In Mississippi Queen, of course, there are two dials per steamboat, but that's a minor detail.

Of course, this is a more expensive implementation than all of the other answers, and will drive up the cost of producing the game, but it's closest to your original image.

Comment: Thank you! This may be the closest thing to what I am talking about. Do you have any idea where I can get plastic pieces such as those? Or decagon shaped... Did they print plastic numbers on the outside?

Comment: The numbers on the outside are stickers. I'm not sure where you could get them, though; they're custom components for the game. You could try "making do" with whatever prototype components you can find while you're designing/testing the game, then having custom components made when you ship the "real thing" to real customers.